# Should I use `get_stylesheet_uri()` or `get_template_directory_uri()` when calling my CSS Stylesheet?

Tags: functions, wp-enqueue-style, css

I am building a WordPress Theme, from the ground up.  At present, I have placed a `style.css` file within the `wp-content/themes/theme-name` directory.  The current information, within this file, is as follows:

```
/*
Theme Name: Theme Name
Theme URI: http://www.example.com/theme-name/
Author: Relevant Author Name
Author URI: http://www.example.com/authors/author-name/
Description: Relevant description.
Version: Version Number
License: GNU General Public License v2 or later
License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
Tags: Relevant Tags
Text Domain: Relevant Name
*/
```

I have also created a `wp-content/themes/theme-name/` directory, which houses my custom stylesheet CSS file.

I am working within my `functions.php` and wondering which is the correct way to call my CSS Stylesheet?

**Method A:**

```
 <?php
     function theme_name_script_enqueue() {
         wp_enqueue_style( 'customstylesheet', get_stylesheet_uri(), array(), '1.0', 'all');
     }
 add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_script_enqueue' );
 ?>
```

Have I got it right, that this then calls the `style.css` within the `wp-content/themes/theme-name/` directory.  How would I then 'link' this CSS file with my Custom CSS file within the `wp-content/themes/theme-name/css/` directory, so that when the `style.css` is also calls my custom CSS file?

**Method B:**

This simply calls the file, housed within the `wp-content/themes/theme-name/css/` directory.

```
<?php
    function theme_name_script_enqueue() {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'customstylesheet', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/css_file_name.css', array(), '1.0', 'all');
    }
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_script_enqueue' );
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Wordpress recommends the proper way to enqueue the main style is the method-A. Please see the WordPress theme development handbook here (though both methods will work). https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/

It's not clear to me why you want to link the two .css file? You can create custom .css file and enqueue it using method-B.

However, if you want to import custom .css file to main style.css file you can use the CSS @import method. The syntex is as follows:

@import url("../theme-name/css/bootstrap.css");